# MangoDB: select where like

Tags: kohana-mangodb

I'm just trying out the Kohana MongoDB ORM: MangoDB. I'm trying to figure out how to do a `where like`.

```
$query['city'] = $this->request->query('location');
$results = Mango::factory('salon')
    ->load(array(
        'limit' => null,
        'criteria' => $query
    ));
```

I want to change this to do a where like:

```
SELECT * FROM salon WHERE city LIKE '%London%'
```

Comment: find("city":/London/) - see section on regular expressions in querying  in MongoDB docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB supports regular expressions:

`db.collection.find( { city: /*London*/i } );`

See documentation here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/regex/